# In MailKit, how do I get the message's raw representation?

Tags: c#, .net, imap, mailkit

I am downloading messages over IMAP using MailFolder.Fetch and then getting the relevant body parts with MailFolder.GetBodyPart.

Is it possible to get the raw representation of the MIME message in addition to the processed information?

Code:

```
var query = CreateSearchQuery(startDate, endDate);
await mailFolder.OpenAsync(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
var results = await mailFolder.SearchAsync(SearchOptions.All, query);
var messageSummaries = await mailFolder.FetchAsync(results.UniqueIds, DownloadFlags);
```

Later I download the message by running over the parts, finding the html and the plain parts and downloading them as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455519/saving-attachments-using-mailkit-library) question (only I download the parts that are not `IsAttachment==true`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you download only individual MIME parts, it won't be possible to get the raw representation of the full message (unless you download *all* of the parts and reconstruct the message), but you *can* get the raw representation of each of the MIME parts that you download by using the `WriteTo()` method that exists on each `MimeEntity` that you get back from `MailFolder.GetBodyPart()`.

If you want the raw representation of the full message, then the easiest way to get that is to use `MailFolder.GetMessage()` and then invoke the `WriteTo()` method on the `MimeMessage` that you get back or you can use `MailFolder.GetStream()` in the following way:

```
var raw = folder.GetStream (uid, string.Empty);
```

I would suggest that if you know that you'll want the full raw message, it's best to avoid downloading individual parts first as it'll just be a waste of bandwidth. If you decide to use `GetStream()`, you can feed the stream to `MimeMessage.Load()` and get back a parsed `MimeMessage` object.

Note: If you use the `WriteTo()` method, don't forget to seek back to 0 in the stream if you want to read the raw message or body part data.

Comment: Thanks, does GetMessage always download the entire message with the attachments? Is it possible to download it without the attachments and still use WriteTo?

Comment: Also, is it possible to get the data behind a Fetch call? That gets only the headers?

Comment: GetMessage() will download the entire message including attachments. The only way to get the message without the attachments is to download the individual body parts as you are currently doing, however, that means you won't be able to have the full raw representation of the message because the full raw message would include the attachments.

Comment: You can request individual headers in a `Fetch()` call, but you can't easily request *all* headers that way. I would recommend using `GetStream (uid, "HEADER")` to get the raw message headers which you can then parse using `HeaderList.Load()` if you want the parsed version.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will simply download the entire message and use the EncodeTo. Thank you very much for this great, high quality library.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, what I need is not necessarily the raw data of a specific message but the evidence that the data I got from the server is the data presented to the user, which actually `WriteTo` isn't doing that exactly since it's converting the data loaded into the C# objects back to a string.

I was going to open up the library and redirect the `ImapStream` to a new type that duplicates the data to another stream, but luckily Jeff has already thought of that and implemented the option to inject a `ProtocolLogger` which already does that.

Hopefully that helps someone in the future.